# Query filtered by list from QuerySelectMultipleField

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

i am python and flask beginner and i need help with WTForms:

I need create query, filtered by values checked in QuerySelectMultipleField.

In my test code i have two lists:

> Dynamic (returned QuerySelectMultipleField) -–> list_d 
>   Static (created
>   manually) --> list_m

List returned from QuerySelectMultipleField is dynamic and values is for example:

```
[Jedna, Dva, Tri]
```

And list created manually:

```
list_m = ['Jedna', 'Dva', 'Tri']
```

MyView:

```
 @admin.route('/tests', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def tests():
        list_d = None
        list_m = None
        items = None
        form = TestForms()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            list_d = form.selectMultiple.data
            list_m = ['Jedna', 'Dva', 'Tri']
            items = Item.query.filter(Item.global_name.in_(list_m)).all()
            # items = Item.query.filter(Item.global_name.in_(list_d)).all()
        return render_template('admin/tests.html',
                               form=form,
                               list_d=list_d,
                               list_m=list_m,
                               items=items,
                               )
```

MyTemplate:

```
<div class="box-body">
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
<p>Dynamic list: {{ list_d }}</p>
<p>Manual list: {{ list_m }}</p>
<p>ITEMS: {{ items }}</p>
</div>
```

MyModel:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    global_name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    item_name1 = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    records = db.relationship('Record', backref='item', lazy='dynamic')

def __init__(self, global_name):
    self.global_name = global_name

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.global_name)
```

MyForm:

```
def select_items():
    return Item.query.all()

class TestForms(Form):
    selectMultiple = QuerySelectMultipleField(query_factory=select_items,
                                              allow_blank=True,
                                              )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**And here is my problem:**
When use list created manually:

```
items = Item.query.filter(Item.global_name.in_(list_m)).all()
```

works all fine and in "items" i see values filterred by values from list_m.

But when use list_d (returned from QuerySelectMultipleField):

```
items = Item.query.filter(Item.global_name.in_(list_d)).all()
```

I get error message:

> builtins.TypeError TypeError: expected string or buffer

and "items" are None :/

Solution is probably simple, but my current skills isn't enough. 
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: It looks like `list_d` already contains the items. You don't need to query for them again.

Comment: Hm, on begin is `list_d = None`. Items contains until after submit form with selected options: "Jedna, Dva, Tri".

Comment: After the form validates you do `list_d = form.selectMultiple.data`. At that point, `list_d` contains the `Item` records you then try to query for with `items = Item.query.filter(Item.global_name.in_(list_d)).all()`. You could just do `items = form.selectMultiple.data` instead.